# How do you find the general expression of a derived sum?

Tags: derivatives, summation

We got an exercice about maximum and  minimum and there is a question about a sum. The goal is to find the general expression of the sum ( without the sigma ). And there is a kx^k form. We need to derive and I can understand why but I just can't find how you derive a sum.

Comment: Probably the question is about finite sum: $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n kx^k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the sum of [geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^k = \dfrac{x(1-x^n)}{1-x}.\tag{1}
$$
Then we can rewrite the sum $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} kx^k$ in the form
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} kx^k =
\sum_{k=1}^{n} x^k  + \sum_{k=2}^{n} x^k  + \sum_{k=3}^{n} x^k  + \ldots + \sum_{k=n-1}^{n} x^k  +  (x^n).  \tag{2}
$$
Based on $(1)$ we continue:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} kx^k =
\dfrac{x(1-x^n)}{1-x}+
\dfrac{x^2(1-x^{n-1})}{1-x}+\dfrac{x^3(1-x^{n-2})}{1-x}+ \ldots + \dfrac{x^{n-1}(1-x^2)}{1-x}+ \dfrac{x^n(1-x)}{1-x} 
$$
$$ 
= \dfrac{x-x^{n+1}}{1-x}+
\dfrac{x^2-x^{n+1}}{1-x}+\dfrac{x^3-x^{n+1}}{1-x}+ \ldots + \dfrac{x^{n-1}-x^{n+1}}{1-x}+ \dfrac{x^{n}-x^{n+1}}{1-x}
$$
$$
= \dfrac{1}{1-x}\left( (x-x^{n+1}) + (x^2-x^{n+1}) + (x^3-x^{n+1}) + \ldots + (x^{n-1}-x^{n+1}) + (x^n - x^{n+1})\right)
$$
$$
= \dfrac{1}{1-x}\left( \sum_{k=1}^{n}x^k-nx^{n+1}\right)
$$
$$
= \dfrac{1}{1-x}\left( \dfrac{x(1-x^n)}{1-x}-nx^{n+1}\right).\tag{3}
$$
And many equivalent modifications: 
$$
\dfrac{1}{x-1}\left(nx^{n+1} -\dfrac{x(x^n-1)}{x-1}\right);
$$
$$
\dfrac{x}{x-1}\left(nx^n -\dfrac{(x^n-1)}{x-1}\right);
$$
$$
\dfrac{x}{(x-1)^2}\left(nx^{n+1} - nx^n -(x^n-1)\right);
$$
$$
\dfrac{x}{(x-1)^2}\left(nx^{n+1} - (n+1)x^n +1\right);
$$
(see [WolframAlpha link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%20kx%5Ek) to check the formula).

Comment: Oh thank you I just fount it and really thank you for the demonstration !!! Have a nice day !!